# Error In C# When I Delete A Row

Tags: c#

I recive 'DeletedRowInaccessible Exception','Deleted Row Information cannot be accessed through the row'.

I Recived this Exception on this Code when Delete a row.

```
BindingSource_ListChanged(-)
{
    payment=(from row in ServiceDataset.ServiceDataset.ServiceOrderPayments
    where row.Code==ServiceOrdersRow.Code
    select row.payment).sum()
}
```

i use this code to calculate sum of payments.

but when i delete a row and rowstate of row set to Deleted I recive this Error.

plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that `ServiceOrderPayments`, assuming it's a table in a typed dataset, would already exclude deleted rows, but if not, simply updating the `where` clause will fix this:

```
where row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted && row.Code == ServiceOrdersRow.Code
```

Though you should also consider the possibility that it's `ServiceOrdersRow` that has been deleted.

Comment: row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted  is not a good idea.

RowState is a [FlagsAttribute] enum,  so the Deleted state can be combined with other states causing the != to be false even when the record is deleted.

(row.RowState & DatarowState.Deleted) == 0

Answer (score 7):

Check the where, there should be a '==':

```
row.Code == ServiceOrdersRow.Code
```

Comment: ok 
sorry

i use '==' in action

but i recive error when i delete a row

i use removecurrent() method to remove a row